# reduce more than one value

Tags: javascript, reduce

Is there any way that I can return more than one object with the reduce function? For example, I want to return the oldest age and I have 3 people who are all the same age. See below, thanks!

```
var dataArray = [
     {name: "Roy", age: 24, sex: "M"},
     {name: "Ben", age: 25, sex: "M"},
     {name: "Jamie", age: 23, sex: "F"},
     {name: "David", age: 25, sex: "M"},
     {name: "Bob", age: 25, sex: "M"}
 ];

 var oldestPeople = dataArray.reduce(function(max, cur) {
     console.log("Max is " + max["name"]);
     console.log("Cur is " + cur["name"]);
     if (cur["age"] === max["age"]) {
         return [max, cur];
     } else if (cur["age"] > max["age"]) {
         return cur;
     } else {
         return max;
     }
 });
```

I am able to get it to return two objects, but my max becomes undefined once [max, cur] is returned. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm getting an array with two objects as you suggest should occur: https://jsfiddle.net/apdht5gx/

Comment: Seems to be working, but a filter seems a lot more appropriate ?

Comment: it would be conceptually simpler to pluck the ages, find the max using `Math.max.apply`, then filter out any objects with ages != to the max... reduce() is really designed for getting one out of many...

Comment: @dandavis—if the "one" is an array of the oldest people, reduce seems fine to me and only requires a single iteration. The only issue is keeping a reference to the oldest age.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

then the first callback it the return value from the previous invocation of the callback.

So the problem you are having is that sometimes you return and array [max,cut] and other times you return a single value cur or max -- just stick to always return an array and you should be fine, like

```
 if (max)
    console.log("Max is " + max[0]["name"]);
 else
    return [cur];
 console.log("Cur is " + cur["name"]);
 if (cur["age"] === max[0]["age"]) {
     return max.concat([cur]);
 } else if (cur["age"] > max[0]["age"]) {
     return [cur].concat(max);
 } else {
     return max.concat([cur]);
 }
```

Comment: MDN isn't *the* documentation (i.e. it's not an authority on ECMAScript), that would be [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). Though MDN is a good resource. ;-)

Comment: MDN would be "the" _JavaScript_ documentation though, which is what this section is called...

Comment: @dandavis—this question though is specific to ECMAScript, the term "javascript" is really just a generic term for the various implementations (including those that do not implement DOM APIs). MDN is a public wiki, anyone can contribute to it, though the quality has increased greatly in the last few years.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `reduce`, you could use something like

```
var oldestPeople = dataArray.reduce(function(max, cur) {
  if (cur.age === max.age) {
    max.people.push(cur);
  } else if (cur.age > max.age) {
    max.age = cur.age;
    max.people = [cur];
  }
  return max;
}, {age: -Infinity, people: []}).people;
```

But maybe I would prefer a `forEach`:

```
var maxAge = -Infinity,
    oldestPeople = [];
dataArray.forEach(function(cur) {
  if (cur.age === maxAge) {
    oldestPeople.push(cur);
  } else if (cur.age > maxAge) {
    maxAge = cur.age;
    oldestPeople = [cur];
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not logical for a person's age to be -ve, so 0 seems a reasonable initial value, though *undefined* is probably better so that if *dataArray* is empty, the maximum age is *undefined* rather than *-Infinity*.

Comment: @RobG The problem with undefined is that `number > undefined` is false. I could use `!(number < undefined)` but I don't like that. That's why in general I use `-Infinity` as the initial argmax. Note `Math.max()` is `-Infinity`, not `undefined` nor `NaN`.